# Azure Devops - Add users to organization without assigning project collection administrator

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Currently, my Azure DevOps account do not have project collection administrator permission.  I can see the "Add user" button if I added the project collection administrator.  Is there a granular role to add a user to an organization without assigning project collection administrator.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the reply helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Add users to organization without assigning project collection
>   administrator

For this issue , unfortunately it is impossible to achieve in azure devops.

This is clearly stated in the official documentation:

> **Prerequisites**
>
> You **must** have **Project Collection Administrator** or
>   **organization Owner** permissions in Azure DevOps. For more information,
>   see [Set permissions at the project level or project collection level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-project-collection-level-permissions?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Faccounts%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Faccounts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops).

For details,please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

If you can see "add user" active button in Project Collection Admin group on the top right hand side, you must be a member of a teams group which is directly or indirectly is a part of a Project collection administrator group. Usually that is done when you are a part of teams group and that teams groups is the part of PCA(Project Collection Admin.

Alternatively, since you wont be able to edit the permissions of PCA, you can create a teams group and add that teams group to PCA and play around with the permissions and you will be add the users to the ORG as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).